# WinUi 3 vs UWP: Serial Port - System.IO.Ports.SerialPort vs Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, .net-6.0, winui

I write this question because I am reconsidering an old project I had developed as a UWP Application, because is an almost 3 years old project I would like to rewrite for WinUi, which if I have understood right (off-topic question) it's the same thing of UWP, but with the necessary packages for WinUi3.

The Application was using quite extensively `SerialDevice` objects which required also the permission for being used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice?view=winrt-22621

Today I downloaded this project (https://github.com/tugsadhk/WinUI3-Serial-Port-Communication) to see how to use the SerialPort with WinUi and saw he is using `using System.IO.Ports;` which is also compatible with WPF and doesn't require any permission in the manifest.

I think I would need a guidance to understand the differences, I suppose that one is using the WinRT libraries and I have no Idea of what is using in System.IO.Ports.

I would like to know is if there is any advantages in using a `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice`  over a `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`

Comment: System.IO.Ports is provided by .NET (Framework, Core) and open source: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports (and I guess cross platform) Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice is closed source Windows only (WinRT) so may provide more pure Windows-oriented capabilities and available to non .NET languages (C++, Delphi, etc.) and to .NET languages, using projections

Comment: Here is a good answer, but what would be helpful to understand, is it better to use the WINRT approach or the openSource one?

My question is also:
Is WinRT compatible with .net6 libraries? What about .NetNative? Does something change?

Sorry for the very basic question, but I am a bit confused

Comment: .NET native is something else (too early to be 100% sure what it will become IMHO). As for is WinRT compatible with .NET6+, answer is yes, since there are projections for C#, C#/WinRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/ which is implicitly used if you use Visual Studio 2022 and use the target platform monikers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#net-6-use-the-target-framework-moniker-option

Comment: Thanks for these resources, very useful... I will read about C# and WinRT...